# Youtube Videos on IOS Not working

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, video, youtube

I am trying to use Youtube Videos link to my website..
I can able to view the videos in all browsers but cant view them on IPads and Iphones.

I am getting the html code as in the link [Click For LINK Here](http://ft.trillian.im/76ffcc8584554af1f38acca4078df15911232ed1/6qVP56GO4LTE50dimYGl8uil8aJrj.jpg) with out getting the Video:

Can you please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

make sure, Does iOS Device support format of video you are linking.